# How to transfer runtime embedded variable to React App.tsx file?

Tags: c, react-native

I have an embedded application running on an esp32. I've created a webserver page using react which created an App.tsx file. I have a variable that controls the state of an led. I keep this state in flash in the chip and when a user logs onto the webpage, I want to be able to use the actual value to initialize the led state on the page. Right now I just set it to false with
const [ledOn, setLedOn] = useState(false);

I am new to React and don't understand how to get the embedded variable in the c code, ie on/off boolean, into the App.tsx file so when the webpage renders it will show the current state of the led.

I'm including the full App.tsx file and if anyone can help me with this it would be much appreciated.
Thanks

```
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [btnState, setBtnState] = useState(true);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [ledOn, setLedOn] = useState(false);   <-----------------------***************

  useEffect(() => {
    getHelloWorld();
    webSocket();
  }, []);

  const getHelloWorld = async () => {
    const webResult = await fetch("/api/hello-world");
    const myText = await webResult.text();
    setMessage(myText);
  };

  const getWebSocketUrl = (suffix: string)=>{
    const l = window.location;
    return ((l.protocol == "https:")? "wss://" : "ws://") + l.host + l.pathname + suffix;
  }
  const webSocket = () => {
    const socket = new WebSocket(getWebSocketUrl("ws"))
    socket.onopen = () => {
      socket.send("Hello ESP32");
    },
    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log(event.data);
      try {
        const AttemptedBtnState = JSON.parse(event.data)
        setBtnState(AttemptedBtnState.btn_state)
      }finally{

      }
    }
    socket.onerror = (err) => console.error(err);
    socket.onclose = (event) => console.log(event);
  };

  const switchLed = async (is_on: boolean) => {
    const payload = { is_on }
    const webResult = await fetch("/api/toggle-led", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    });
    if(!webResult.ok) {
      console.error(webResult.statusText);
      return;
    }
    setLedOn(is_on);
  };

  const getLEDText = () => ledOn? "LED is on" : "LED is off"

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>LearnEsp32</h1>
      <h1>
        {message}
      </h1>
      <div className="card">
        <button 
          style={{background:ledOn? "lightBlue" : "" }} 
          onClick={() => switchLed(!ledOn)}>
          {getLEDText()}
        </button>
      <div style = {{ 
        width: "50px", 
        height: "50px", 
        border: "1px solid black", 
        margin: "auto",
        borderRadius: "50px",
        marginTop: "16px",
        background: btnState? "pink" : "",
        }}>
      </div>
      </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: How is this connected to C? There is no C code in the question.

Comment: This app.tsx file is stored in flash on the chip. When a client connects to the web page it is served as json. It's built using react and stored as files on the chip. The main embedded code is also running on the chip. I just need to be able to get the runtime c code variable, say ledonoff (a bool) to be served to the client on init connect.

Comment: const [ledOn, setLedOn] = useState(false); in app.tsx(in flash) is setting the led state to off  when the client connects. I need to be able to set it as follows from the c code:         const [ledOn, setLedOn] = useState({current led state});

Comment: Here is the c code

Comment: void set_led(int whichled, int ledstate)
{
  gpio_set_level(whichled, ledstate);
}